# How best to compare images of 2D shapes

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I have a series of images containing red shapes like this:
[image]

I want to be able to extract different shapes like these:

[image][image][image]

...without extracting images that are too similar to those already extracted, like these:

[image][image]

As you can see, the size of each image varies, but they all follow a general shape.

What would be the best algorithm in this situation? I have tried some other image comparison algorithms but they are designed for full colour, detailed images and don't provide the granularity I need with my 'binary' shapes.

Comment: Discarding the too similar shapes is not a big deal. But you should show us counterexamples, i.e. shapes that must be rejected for being too different.

Comment: Thanks for the comment- any of the ones in the 2nd row should be rejected if compared to one in the 3rd row. Perhaps I should have reworded my question to be more clear about that, sorry.

Comment: Now even unclearer.